# Win32 UTF-16 character indexing

Tags: string, winapi, unicode, utf-16

I'm just starting out with Win32 unicode strings (UTF-16). Is there any way to quickly obtain the byte index of any particular character in the string, since some characters might use four bytes (from what I gather reading MSDN)? Or should they all be considered two bytes per character?

Comment: Some characters can be even larger due to composition. First you need to define what you mean by "character". Do you mean code point, or glyph, or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure of some of the terminology used here. In SBCS strings, each byte was a "character." Now with UTF, each 2bytes might be a character, but maybe more, due to the encoding. Is the only way to figure out the index of a specific character to start at the beginning character and traverse through it one at a time until the destination character has been reached?

Comment: The question is what are you trying to accomplish? Unless you develop a Unicode algorithm (which you shouldn't since it's very complicated) or implement some input/output method (like implementing an edit control or text rendering engine from scratch) you don't even need to worry about "characters" and encodings. [If you do, you're doing something wrong.](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CharNext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CharPrev()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs can be used to safely walk UNICODE strings on Windows.

To obtain the nth character of a UNICODE string, call CharNext() in a loop.